# Install an .MSI file from the same directory as the powershell script without setting a static file path

Tags: powershell, installation, windows-installer

I have a script that we use that is in Powershell however I need the script to be able to find the files that it needs to install an application dynamically as users can copy the folder to any folder on their computer. Currently I have the below code set, I guess my question is, if the script is in the same folder as the install files. How do I tell powershell to just look in the directory that its being ran from for the install files?

```
$Install = "C:\Other Folder\File.msi"
$InstallArg = "/quite /norestart"
     Start-Process '
     -FilePath $Install '
     -ArgumentList $InstallArg '
     -PassThru | Wait-Process
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Update, I found that I have to be in the directory the script is in. However since we have to run ISE with admin credentials it automatically defaults to C:\Windows\System32 as the directory powershell is looking in regardless if I tell it to open the script. If that is the case how can I tell it to look where the script is located so that it can find the files that it needs?

Answer (score 0):

Define a relative path:

```
$Install = ".\File.msi"
```

If you are not running the script inside the directory, where the script itself and the executable are stored, you will have to determine the absolute path to it. With PowerShell 3+ you can easily determine the directory, where your script is stored, using the `$PSScriptRoot` variable. You could define your `$Install` variable like this:

```
$Install = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "File.msi"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer below is how I got it to work with our current situation. Thank you Thomas for the help!

```
$ScriptLocation = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users -Filter Untitled2.ps1 -Recurse | Select Directory
cd $ScriptLocation.Directory
$Install = ".\Install.msi"
$InstallArg = "/quite /norestart"
Start-Process '
-FilePath $Install '
-ArgumentList $InstallArg '
-PassThru | Wait-Process
```

Comment: This might work under some circumstances. It will fail, after your script has been renamed, or if it is not stored somewhere under `C:\Users` or if there is more than one file called `Untitled2.ps1`. All in all pretty dangerous. I updated my answer for your problem, you might want to prefer that way.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help everyone! I accidentally stumbled upon the perfect solution.

```
# Set active path to script-location:
$path = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
if (!$path) {
    $path = $psISE.CurrentFile.Fullpath
}
if ($path) {
    $path = Split-Path $path -Parent
}
Set-Location $path
```